# How to retrieve cell values of selected rows in grid view when page index is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to store data of multiple selected rows from my gridview into SQL server when the user changes the page index of the gridview, but I am unable to do it in the event of PageIndexChanging. However, I am able to do it on a button postback. Any guidance on how to do it would be much appreciated.

My gridview properties of AllowPaging is True and AutoGenrateColumns is False, I am using Bounded Fields

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    string query2 = "select QuestionID, QuestionText, q.QuizID, TopicID from StandardQuizData qd, Questions q where qd.TopicID='" + Request.QueryString["UserCustomQuizTopicID"].ToString() + "' AND qd.QuizID = q.QuizID";
    var adapt2 = new SqlDataAdapter(query2, connString);
    var comm2 = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapt2);
    var ds2 = new DataSet();
    adapt2.Fill(ds2, "Questions");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds2;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    try
    {
        DataTable tableUserInput = QuestionDS.Tables.Add("QuestionSelect");
        tableUserInput.Columns.Add("CustomQuizQID", typeof(String));
        tableUserInput.Columns.Add("UserID", typeof(String));
        tableUserInput.Columns.Add("QuizID", typeof(String));
        tableUserInput.Columns.Add("TopicID", typeof(String));
        tableUserInput.Columns.Add("QuestionID", typeof(String));
        tableUserInput.Columns.Add("QuestionName", typeof(String));


        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow drow = tableUserInput.NewRow();
            var checkbox = gvrow.FindControl("CheckBoxSelect") as CheckBox;
            if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                drow["UserID"] = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
                drow["QuizID"] = Request.QueryString["UserCustomQuizID"].ToString();
                drow["TopicID"] = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
                drow["QuestionID"] = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
                drow["QuestionName"] = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
                tableUserInput.Rows.Add(drow);
                Qnumber++;
            }

        }

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                "CustomQuizQuestions";

            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(tableUserInput);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this??

Comment: @HussainMd I'm trying to create a custom list of questions in SQL Server that is selected by the user, the questions are showed to the user in Gridview and selected using checkboxes, but because of the large number of questions the Gridview expands to multiple pages and I would like to store the questions the user has already selected when moving on to a new page in the gridview

Comment: do you have both select row and select all rows functionality in grid( per page )?

Comment: @HussainMd No. Only select row, User selects each row one by one using a checkbox provided in the row